# Sending quotation marks in a GCM Payload (and other special characters that break syntax)

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, google-cloud-messaging

I'm struggling finding a feasible solution to this. I've tried looking around but can't find any documentation regarding this issue. If a customer sends out a message with quote(s), it break the payload syntax and android spits me back a 400 Bad Request error.

The only solution I can think of is by doing my own translations and validations. Allow only the basics, and for the restricted do my own "parsing" Ie take a quote, replace them with "/q" and then replace "/q" on the App when received. I don't like this solution because it involves logic on the App that if, I forget something. I want to be able to change it immediately rather then update everyones phone, app, etc.

I'm looking for an existing encoding I could apply that is processed correctly by the GCM servers. Allowing them to be accepted then broadcasted. Received by the phone with the characters intact.

Answer (score 1):

Base64 encoding should get rid of the special characters. Just encode it before sending and decode it again on receiving:

**Edit:** sorry, just got a java/android sample here, I don't know how exactly xamarin works and what functions it provides:

```
// before sending
byte[] data = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
String base64Message = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);

// on receiving
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64Message , Base64.DEFAULT);
String message= new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Beautiful! This should do it, thanks! I wrote a bit in that brutally trims down the text based on it's encoded length Ie looping `(4 * (Int32)Math.Ceiling(postDataBytes.Length / 3.0))` removing a character at a time. This is to keep it in the size limit of payload we're under per GCM.

Comment: That's alright. I'm pretty good at translating. To decode `Byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString); String decoded = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);`, to encode `Byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decodedString); String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);`

Answer (score 0):

.Net translation of @tknell solution

Decode:

```
Byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString); 
String decoded = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Encode:

```
Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decodedString); 
String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(data);
```